# Splitting a Decimal Value(as String ) using java

Tags: java

I am converting a Decimal number to string and then i am splitting the number(String) using the .(Dot) operator.

For Ex:

```
double x=Math.sqrt(17);//4.12425325
String str=String.valueOf(x);
String ar[]=str.split(".");//But its not getting splitted.
```

But the String is not getting splitted into String Array ar[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

escape the `.` in `split()`

```
String ar[]=str.split("\\.");
```

argument to `split()` is a regex and `.` has a special  meaning in regex ,so to match a literal `.` , you need to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

`Split()` accepts a `Regex` as an argument. So, we need to escape the '.' here as '.' means *any character* in `Regex`, e.g.:

```
String s = "123.456";
String[] split = s.split("\\.");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to get the whole number portion and the decimal portion.

```
String num = "123.45";
System.out.println( num.substring( 0, num.indexOf(".") ) ); // prints whole number part
System.out.println( num.substring( num.indexOf(".") + 1) ); // prints decimal part
```

If you are interested in just the contents of both the decimal and the whole number portions, this method doesn't involve using an array.